# Angular JS watch factory variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory variable which is shared by two directives. One directives changes it and I need it to update the value in other directive as well.

This is my factory code

```
commonApp.factory('setSmsMessage', [function () {
var factoryObj = {
    data: {
        isSms: false
    },
    setSms: function () {
        factoryObj.data.isSms = true;
    },
    reset: function () {
        factoryObj.data.isSms = false;
    }
};

return factoryObj;
```

}]);

This is my one directive

```
commonApp.directive('osSendMessage', ['setSmsMessage',
function (setSmsMessage) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        sent: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    controller: function ($scope) {


        $scope.setSmsMessage = setSmsMessage.data;

        $scope.$watch('setSmsMessage.isSms', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
            console.log(setSmsMessage.data.isSms);
        }, true);

    },
    templateUrl: "/Static/js/AngularApps/MessageCenter/sendmessage/Templates/sendmessages.html"
};
}]);
```

This is my other directive which sets the variable

```
commonApp.directive('osMessageCenterMenu', ['setSmsMessage', function (setSmsMessage) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        messages: "="
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {

    },
    link: function (scope) {


        // opening sms

        $("#toggleSendSmsMessage").click(function () {
            scope.openSendSms();
        });
        scope.openSendSms = function () {
            console.log("from menu: " + setSmsMessage.data.isSms);
            setSmsMessage.setSms();
            console.log("from menu: " + setSmsMessage.data.isSms);

            $("#SendMessageForm").toggle();
        }

        // end here
        ,

    templateUrl: "/Static/js/AngularApps/MessageCenter/Templates/messageCenterMenu.html"
};
}]);
```

But the value is not updated in the other controller which is listening to it

Comment: That call to `$watch` looks fishy. You aren't telling it what to watch. Also there are some problems with your design. You should name the factory `smsMessage` and any method named `setX` should take an argument or be renamed.

Comment: The watch code I got online. Yeah I would fix the naming convention.

Comment: Could it be because both the directives have there seperate instances of the factory object? And changing one doesn't change the other?

Comment: Ah, yeah. Now its much more clear. You are messing with jquery, which is a bad practice, as angularjs not knows you updated the value.

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: after `scope.openSendSms();` call `scope.$apply()`

Comment: doesn't work, can you please, update the answer?

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Ive updated the fiddle, and without the `scope.$apply()` it works aswell.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to store the `isSms` property in a global `object` like so:

```
commonApp.factory('setSmsMessage', [function ()
{
    var factoryObj = {
        data: {
            isSms: false
        },
        setSms: function ()
        {
            factoryObj.data.isSms = true;
        },
        reset: function ()
        {
            factoryObj.data.isSms = false;
        }
    };

    return factoryObj;
}]);
```

Now in your controller link the `$scope` to the factories global `object` which holds the `isSms` property.

```
// Link setSmsMessage to the factories data object
$scope.setSmsMessage = setSmsMessage.data;

// Now call the setSms() function. The $scope.setSmsMessage will be updated after the call.
setSmsMessage.setSms();

// You can now watch for changes in the $scope like so
$scope.$watch('setSmsMessage.isSms', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
    console.log(setSmsMessage.data.isSms);
}, true);
```

**Working demo**

```js
(function() {

  var commonApp = angular.module("app", []);
  
  commonApp.factory('setSmsMessage', [function ()
  {
    var factoryObj = {
        data: {
            isSms: false
        },
        setSms: function ()
        {
            factoryObj.data.isSms = true;
        },
        reset: function ()
        {
            factoryObj.data.isSms = false;
        }
    };

    return factoryObj;
  }]);
  
  commonApp.controller("smsController", function($scope, setSmsMessage) {
    // Link setSmsMessage to the factories data object
    $scope.setSmsMessage = setSmsMessage.data;
  
    // Now call the setSms() function. The $scope.setSmsMessage will be updated after the call.
    setSmsMessage.setSms();
    
    $scope.reset = function()
    {
      setSmsMessage.reset();
    }

    $scope.$watch('setSmsMessage.isSms', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
        console.log(setSmsMessage.data.isSms);
    }, true);
  });
  
commonApp.directive('osMessageCenterMenu', ['setSmsMessage', function (setSmsMessage)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            messages: "="
        },
        controller: function ($scope)
        {

        },
        link: function (scope)
        {
            console.log(scope);

            // opening sms

            $("#toggleSendSmsMessage").click(function ()
            {
                scope.openSendSms();
            });
            scope.openSendSms = function ()
            {
                console.log("from menu: " + setSmsMessage.data.isSms);
                setSmsMessage.setSms();
                console.log("from menu: " + setSmsMessage.data.isSms);

                $("#SendMessageForm").toggle();
            }
        }
    }
}]);

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="smsController">
    <div os-message-center-menu>
      <button id="toggleSendSmsMessage">reset message</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but what I am trying to do is update the value from a different controller and get the value in the different controller. So I am trying to call setSmsMessage.setSms() from a different controller

Comment: Just inject the setSmsMessage into that controller?

Answer (score 0):

you can also work with `$rootScope` in your factory and `emit` an event with `custom data` and then `subscribe` to the `event` in all your `controllers`

> Also, try naming your `factory` based on functionality, for obvious
>   reasons.

Following is what am trying to say :-

```js
(function() {
  angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .factory('smsMessage', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var factoryObj = {
      data: {
        isSms: false
      },
      setSms: function() {
        factoryObj.data.isSms = true;
        $rootScope.$emit('SET', {isSms : true});
      },
      reSet: function() {
        factoryObj.data.isSms = false;
        $rootScope.$emit('RE-SET', {isSms : false});
      }
    };
    return factoryObj;
  }])
  .controller("controllerOne", function($scope, $rootScope, smsMessage) {
    
    $scope.setSmsMessage = smsMessage.data;
    $scope.set = function(){
        smsMessage.setSms();
    }
    $scope.reset = function(){
        smsMessage.reSet();
    }
    
    $rootScope.$on('SET', function(event, data) {
      alert('SET in controllerOne');
      $scope.setSmsMessage = data.isSms;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('RE-SET', function(event, data) {
      alert('RE-SET in controllerOne');
      $scope.setSmsMessage = data.isSms;
    });
  })
  .controller("controllerTwo", function($scope, $rootScope, smsMessage) {
    
    $scope.setSmsMessage = smsMessage.data;
    $scope.set = function(){
        smsMessage.setSms();
    }
    $scope.reset = function(){
        smsMessage.reSet();
    }

    $rootScope.$on('SET', function(event, data) {
      alert('SET in controllerTwo');
      $scope.setSmsMessage = data.isSms;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('RE-SET', function(event, data) {
      alert('RE-SET in controllerTwo');
      $scope.setSmsMessage = data.isSms;
    });
  });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="controllerOne">
      <label>Controller One</label>
      <button ng-click="set()">SET</button>
      <button ng-click="reset()">RE-SET</button>
   </div>
  <div ng-controller="controllerTwo">
      <label>Controller Two</label>
      <button ng-click="set()">SET</button>
      <button ng-click="reset()">RE-SET</button>
   </div>
</div>
```